# Adding +1 to a cookie value on click of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

On first page load a cookie is set and has a value of 0.

Basically each time a `div` is clicked the person (this is only for guests) earns 1 EXP, so I need to change the cookie value each time the `div` is clicked by +1. The page won't be refreshed so it needs to store the cookie and show it live, i.e. "You have earned 50 EXP", then click, "You have earned 51 EXP" without a refresh. However the value also needs to stay put if they refresh too.

I found some code on stackoverflow but I'm not sure how to relate it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //set exp cookie
    setCookie("exp", '0');

    //getting the value of exp cookie and assigning it to a variable
    var expCookieCount = getCookie("exp");

    $("#div").one("click",function(){

        expCookieCount++;

        //set the incremented value of expCookieCount variable to exp cookie
        setCookie("exp",expCookieCount);

        // assigning the value of expCookiecount to variable 123
        var 123 = getCookie("exp");

    });

});
```

Comment: Can you specify your question more precisely? Basically you already posted the solution to your problem.

Comment: It would be a lot more efficient to only GET the cookie at the start of the game, and only UPDATE it every x amount of seconds or minutes. Just use a local variable to store the "EXP" and update the cookie with it on a timer.

Comment: `var 123 = getCookie("exp");` That's not a valid variable name

Comment: The code itself doesn't seem to work, I have a div that overlays on top on click but that isn't happening. If I remove all the cookie code it works.

Comment: You need to include the cookie plugin too

Comment: See my answer.... jQuery cookie plugin or valid JavaScript cookie code. get/setCookie is not native JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to include [a valid cookie script](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) or use the jQuery [cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). Neither JS nor jQuery have native support for cookies.
2. You need to initialise the cookie if it does not exist:

Like this

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/LLtt9g6L/)

```
function showExp(exp) {
  $("#someSpan").text("You have "+exp+" point"+(exp==1?"":"s"));
}

$(function(){
  //set exp cookie
  var exp = $.cookie("exp");
  exp = (exp)?parseInt(exp,10):0;
  showExp(exp);

  //getting the value of exp cookie and assigning it to a variable
  $("#div").one("click",function(){ // use .on if you want every click to count
    exp++;
    //set the incremented value of expCookieCount variable to exp cookie
    $.cookie("exp",exp,{ expires: 30, path: '/' }); // expiry date 30 days
    showExp(exp);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setCookie("exp", '0');
```

This part of your code will set `exp` to 0 every refresh. You should first check if the user already has an `exp` cookie set before setting it to zero.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var exp = getCookie("exp");

    // Im assuming your getCookie function returns "" when cookie is not present
    if(exp===""){
        //set exp cookie
        setCookie("exp", '0');
        exp = 0;
    } else {
        // Just to make sure it's an integer I had to use parseInt()
        exp = parseInt(exp)
    }

    $("#div").one("click",function(){
        exp++;
        //set the incremented value of expCookieCount variable to exp cookie
        setCookie("exp", exp);

    });

});
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to do that?